# SyntaxError in python. Noob seeking understanding

Tags: python, syntax

I'm following some online python tutorials and i ran across this syntax error code twice now and can't figure out what's wrong.

Here's my code:

```
import urllib
import re

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL")
htmltext = htmlfile.read()

regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_aapl">(.+?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
price = re.findall(pattern, html)

print price
```

I am using Enthought Python Distribution package (python version 2.7.3)

Here's the syntax error when i run the above script.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\scripts\stocks.py", line 4, in <module>
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL")
  File "e:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "e:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 207, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "e:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 291, in open_http
    import httplib
  File "e:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 79, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "e:\python27\lib\mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "e:\python27\lib\tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "E:\python\scripts\random.py", line 1
    def random
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried searching around to understand what's going on but no avail. What's python trying to tell me with all these traceback lines and why do I get a syntax error?

Comment: It looks like you have an (incomplete?) file called random.py in your directory that conflicts with a system library with the same name. Try changing the name of your random.py

Comment: Also note that you have used 'html' as argument instead of 'htmltext'  in re.findall()  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace, towards the bottom, you can see that the syntax error is in a file called `E:\python\scripts\random.py`. This script is one you've added to the system, and it appears to contain a syntax error. Because it's named `random` and is located in the `Scripts` directory, it is "overriding" the built-in `random` library.

Remove or rename that file and you should be good to go.

Comment: ah perfect, i did have a random.py script. Thank you. So why doesn't python access the random.py library in the python27/lib folder instead of whichever folder the script is being run from?

Comment: @user2241963: Because the default is to look *first* in the directory you're in, before looking for packages.

Comment: s/you're/the script is/

Comment: @user2241963: See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path for more details on how the `import` module search finds what it's looking for. Basically, the input script directory is always searched in first.

Answer (score 1):

The import of `module` is controlled by `sys.path`. To a first approximation when your program executes `import module` the interpreter visits the directories on `sys.path` in turn. It looks for a `module.pyc` file and a `module.py` file in each directory, moving on to the next if it finds neither. When it finds one or both, if the `.py` is newer than the `.pyc` (in other words, if the source has been modified since the file was last compiled, or if the compiled file does not exist) then the interpreter compiles the `.py` file and attempts to write to it. There are no guarantees your process will be able to write in that particular directory.

Having identified the correct file the interpreter creates a new namespace, executes the code of the module with that namespace as local, then binds the name of the module with the namespace just created. So if you have bound a name in `module` it should (modulo any `__all__` assignment in the module's code) be available within your importing module as `module.name`.

I suspect this question has taught you why it's not a good idea to duplicate the names of system libraries in your own code - a lesson we all have to learn!

Comment: Indeed it has. Thanks for the in depth answer which cemented this concept. Cheers!

Comment: Something else: the interpreter also looks for a directory called `module` containing a file called `__init__.py[c]`. On finding such a _package_ the interpreter executes the `--init__.py` code in a new namespace and binds the package name to it.